# Are fibonnaci digits essentially random?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, normal-number

I've been toying around with making musical patterns from the Fibonnacci numbers, and looked on YouTube to see what people have done with this. I found the following video, which I do not find very convincing:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGJeGOw8TzQ

The reason I think it's unconvincing is that he's playing the digits of the Fibonacci numbers:

1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5...

...and to me these digits sound more or less random. But I was wondering: is this true in some sense?

I know random is not quite the right word... I remember reading about whether pi is a normal number, and I guess I'm asking something along those lines.

Comment: The last digits of the Fibonacci numbers get eventually periodic , but here all digits are listed and the first digits are in the long run unpredictable. Of course the sequence is not really random, but as shown below, it behaves like a random sequence. Concerning $\pi$ , is is strangely widely believed that it is normal although the only evidence is the huge amount of calculated digits supporting this claim. We can however not even rule out that eventually , only the digits $0$ and $1$ occur , for example.

Comment: @Peter The first digits are fairly predictable in the long run - but they do predictably contain every possible initial sequence of digits, which might be what you meant.

Comment: @MishaLavrov So, we can determine the first digits of $F_{10^{10^{100}}}$ ? I doubt.

Comment: @Peter There's a big gap between "unpredictable" and "so simple that we can do computations with $10^{10^{100}}$." It looks like Mathematica on my laptop is happy to figure out the first digits of $F_{10^{15}}$ much more quickly than it can figure out what $F_{10^{15}}$ actually is, which seems fairly predictable to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The paper [The Fibonacci Sequence is Normal Base 10](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08986) by Benfield and Manes shows that in the sequence $11235813213455\dots$, every $k$-digit block occurs equally often in the long run. So if one played the digits of sufficiently large Fibonacci numbers on the piano, it would be essentially equivalent to playing random notes.

If we begin with the first few Fibonacci numbers, there will still be discernible patterns: knowing the first digit of one Fibonacci number lets you make a good guess at the first digit of the next Fibonacci number, and early on that's a good prediction of what happens 3-4 notes later. I'm unconvinced that those slight correlations will make meaningful musical sense, however.

Comment: Could not have asked for a more perfect response! I was wondering whether someone had written a paper about this, and apparently they have.